# Invoke programmatically iOS App Extensions

Tags: ios, action, ios-app-extension

After reading on Apple documentation and checking on stackoverflow, I could not completely understand if it is possible or not to invoke programmatically an specific app extension of type "Action" or "Share".

Mainly, I have built an app extension of type "Action" and I'd like to invoke it programmatically from a second app (so I can send some input attributes and get the output from the extension) without having to open the UIActivityViewController.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly. The way to invoke other action in other app is to use custom URL Scheme as mentioned in the Apple docs - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW8

You can than pass some arguments as mentioned in the docs, and in your other app you'll need to parse the URL and act according to those parameters.

Comment: However, using this approach of the URL Scheme, I cannot pass files for example, only "URL arguments". In my case I want to pass a PDF file and get as callback another PDF file. Using App Extensions this is very easy as there are a list of "input" parameters and a list of "output" parameters. However using the URL scheme approach it is not. That's why I was wondering on invoking the ios-app-extension programmatically.

Comment: You can have a shared storage for both apps and save the pdf there, and than just pass it's name as parameter. Will this work for you?

Comment: Well, not really, as my "extension" is supposed to work with all apps, not only with mine. Therefore I cannot setup a shared storage. :/

Comment: @vilanovi - You could convert the PDF to a Base64 string and pass it back and forth.